# Are the Flex API's needed to use Haxe with FDT5

Tags: apache-flex, haxe, fdt

I installed FDT5 and it gave me a warning about missing APIs. But [at the FAQ](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/FAQ#Do_I_need_The_Flex_SDKs_to_use_haXe) it said the APIs weren't needed to use Haxe. Yet while trying to follow the Haxe FDT5 tutorial, it says to create a new FDT project. But FDT5 won't let me do this. It gives an error that the required SDK's aren't installed. So do I need to install Flex anyway? Or is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: There tutorial is here: http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/An_Overview_of_haXe_%26_FDT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, either add the 3.6 & 4.5 Flex SDKs to FDT or wait till the 5.5 release which is due this month.

While you don't need the Flex SDKs to USE Haxe & FDT, there is a bug in the scenario when someone wants to use FDT for Haxe only, doesn't setup the Flex SDKs and tries to create a new project.

The bug is that when you try to create a new project, FDT's New Project Wizard will check to make sure that Flex SDKs are linked to FDT. This is to prevent customers from creating broken ActionScript projects. This is good for AS developers but a pain for Haxe only developers - who don't need the Flex SDKs.

Once you add the Flex SDKs, FDT will not warn you about missing SDKs when you try to create a Haxe project.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using extern classes. Write what you want on mxml or as. Compile it into swf (or swc). You can use it with help of extern classes. Look [here](http://haxe.org/doc/js/extern_libraries) for detais.